# AJAX is not sending request

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have the following code:

```
$("form").submit(function()
{
    //Checking data here:
    $("input").each(function(i, obj)
    {
    });
    alert(JSON.stringify($(this).serializeArray()));
    var url='http://127.0.0.1:1337/receive';
    $.ajax({
        url: url,
        type: 'POST',
        contentType:'application/json',
        data: JSON.stringify($(this).serializeArray()),
        dataType:'json'
    });
});
```

And after I submit the form, I get a JavaScript alert with the json string, so that is made correct (on my server I only log it so it does not matter what it is in it). If I try to send a request to the same link from postman it works, it logs it.

I think I'm doing something wrong in the ajax call, but I am not able to figure out.

Comment: dont you have any success handler?

Comment: What @AnoopJoshi said and also where are you defining `url` ?

Comment: @RobSchmuecker url is defined just above the ajax call.

Comment: I do not know how to make the succes handler, and url is defined right above the ajax call (var url='http://127.0.0.1:1337/receive';)

Comment: @AnoopJoshi Right you are :O whoops !

Answer (score 0):

Try below piece of code. Add success and error handler for more details

```
  $("form").submit(function()
    {
        //Checking data here:
        $("input").each(function(i, obj)
        {
        });
        alert(JSON.stringify($(this).serializeArray()));
        var url='http://127.0.0.1:1337/receive';
        $.ajax({
            url: url,
            type: 'POST',
            contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
            data: JSON.stringify($(this).serializeArray()),
            dataType:'json',
            success : function(response) {
                 alert("success");
            },
            error: function (xhr, status, error) {
                     alert(error);
            }
        });
    });
```

Comment: I've added a "," after the success bracket to you code, otherwise it did not work, after the json n alert I get an empty one

Answer (score 0):

data:{ list : JSON.stringify($(this).serializeArray())}

Comment: It does not sent anything this way either.

Comment: $.ajax({
                    url: "url",
                    type: "Post",
                    data: {
                        serializedCkechList: JSON.stringify(list)
                    }
                }).success(function (result) {                  
                        $('#c_c').html(result);
                    
                });Oak ,so you use like this way

Answer (score 0):

From the Jquery docs:
Due to browser security restrictions, most "Ajax" requests are subject to the same origin policy; the request can not successfully retrieve data from a different domain, subdomain, or protocol.

crossDomain attribute simply force the request to be cross-domain. dataType is jsonp and there is a parameter added to the url.

```
$.ajax({    
url:'http://127.0.0.1:1337/receive',    
data:{ apikey: 'secret-key-or-any-other-parameter-in-json-format' },    
dataType:'jsonp',    
crossDomain: 'true',    
success:function (data) {alert(data.first_name);}    
});
```